# Inserting a value into an array gives it a negative index

Tags: php, arrays

For some reason, in one environment, when I insert a value into an array, it pushes with a negative index. The 'original' and 'newOne' are just to show how I am manipulating the array before getting to the weird part, I'm not sure if this is related to the problem:

```
$original = [];
$original[-7] = 'first';
$original[-6] = 'second';

$newOne = [];

$newOne = $original + $newOne;

$newOne[] = 'third';
```

printing this:

```
Array
(
    [-7] => first
    [-6] => second
    [-5] => third
)
```

In another environment and in 3 different online PHP websites that I tested, the code above would work out as expected, printing:

```
Array
(
    [-7] => first
    [-6] => second
    [0] => third
)
```

In those online PHP websites I've tested from PHP 5.6 to 8.1 and the result was aways this.

My question is: Why does the index from `$newOne[] = 'third';` becomes -5, when it should always be 0?

Comment: It gets `0` as you shown? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Caio. The element is being push to the next spot of the array. In your case, after -6 comes -5. Out of curiosity, Why would you want to use negative values for an array index?

Comment: Now you made me curious: Which version of PHP is running in the environment that gives you a `-5`?

Comment: @NicolasTome it's some legacy code, there are many positive indexes in this array, and someone wanted to insert new ones to be executed before, so they used negative values, but as KIKO answered, that isn't viable with PHP 8 anymore, so I'll be changing that ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created by own code and ran it in various PHP versions:

```
$original = [-7 => 'first',
             -6 => 'second'];

$original[] = 'third';

print_r($original);
```

The result might be of interest to you. Output for 8.0.1 - 8.0.25, 8.1.0 - 8.1.12, 8.2rc1 - rc3 is:

```
Array
(
    [-7] => first
    [-6] => second
    [-5] => third
)
```

and the output for 7.4.0 - 7.4.32 is:

```
Array
(
    [-7] => first
    [-6] => second
    [0] => third
)
```

See: : https://3v4l.org/a0GJj

A very short answer to your question would therefore be that the question is wrong. The code that you say results in the -5 key isn't actually the code that you run.

PHP 8.0 changed how it increments negative numeric array keys. The thing you see in the above example has been documented here: [PHP 8.0: Implicit negative array key increments do not skip negative numbers](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/negative-array-keys)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it really is the PHP version, trying in 7.4 always give the [0] => 'third'. But there's one thing still bothering me, there's a difference between my code and yours, using 2 arrays like I did still does show as [0].
Heres the code I ran comparing both versions: https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5eLlUskvykzPzEvMUbBVSCwqSqzU0LRGEo3WNY8FyqinZRYVl6ijypiBZYpTk_PzUkBSQMm81HL_vFSgcHSsNTIXYYu2AlQUIR8NNqckI7MIakxBUWZeSXyRBlReE2J2dmZ2PshkXXMFWzuYi3QUdM3AXKgzwNaCVOI2FCSraQ0A&v=8.0.25%2C7.4.32

Comment: @CaioLeonardo I agree that this looks strange, but remember that you start an array with `$original = array();` thereby setting the first automatic key to zero. If you use keys that are lower, as in your example, they are used but don't increase the automatic key counter. Remove `$original = array();` and it works as in my example.

Comment: @CaioLeonardo I've tried to look for some "prove" that initializing an array reset the automatic index to zero, but I can't find it. I didn't look in the source code of PHP though. But think about it: You initialize an array with `$array = [];` and then you add a value with `$array[] = "value";`, then PHP has to take the current automatic index. What will that be? It has to be zero. So, my assumption that initializing an array sets the automatic index to zero isn't all that strange.